# Finding the longest path in an undirected weighted tree

Tags: graph-algorithm

I have a tree where each edge is assigned a weight (a real number that can be positive or negative). I need an algorithm to find a simple path of maximum total weight (that is, a simple path where the sum of the weights of the edges in the path is maximum). There's no restriction on what node the path starts or ends.

I have a possible algorithm, but I am not sure it works and I am looking for a proof. Here it is:

1. Select an arbitrary node *u* and run DFS(*u*) to find the maximum weight simple path that starts at *u*. Let (*u*, *v*) be this path.
2. Run DFS(*v*) to find the maximum weight simple path that starts at *v*. Let this path be (*v*, *z*).

Then (*v*, *z*) is a simple path of maximum weight. This algorithm is linear in the size of the graph. Can anyone tell me if it works, and if so, give a proof?

**Note:** The [Longest Path Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_path_problem) is NP-Hard for a general graph with cycles. However, I only consider trees here.

Comment: I suppose [math SE](http://math.stackexchange.com/) is a better place to discuss algorithms and proofs

Comment: @Veger: I wasn't sure where it would fit better. I have seen good answers on algorithms and proofs here, more than at Math.SE. In any case, I just posted a duplicate of this question at [math.SE](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/279265/10063).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you allow negative weights then consider the following example:

```
a<->b : -5000
a<->c : 1
b<->d : 1
b<->e : 1
```

The longest path is *d<->b<->e* with length 2

Arbitrarily pick *a* to start. DFS returns *c* with a distance of 1. Second DFS returns *a* with a distance of 1. However *a<->c* is not the longest path.

Comment: As you say, the longest path problem is NP-Hard **in general**. I am talking about a **tree** here, not a general graph with cycles.

Comment: @becko Indeed, I missed that rather important part.

Comment: @becko I edited my answer to provide a counter-example if you allow negative weights.

Comment: +1 Nice and simple counter example. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

here's a proof that it works. The algorithm finds a pair of nodes x0,y0 such that max_x d(x,x0) = max_y d(x0,y) (that is, x0 and y0 are each others' farthest nodes). For any such pair, d(x0,y0) is the diameter. Proof: let x*,y* be two nodes s.t. d(x*,y*) is the diameter. there exist nodes r and s such so that the paths look like x0--r--s--y0 and x*--r--s--y*. Suppose d(x0,y0) < d(x*,y*), then either d(x0,y*) > d(x0,y0) or d(y*,x0) > d(y0,x0), contradicting the fact that x0 and y0 are each others' farthest points. therefore d(x0,y0)=d(x*,y*)

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure there are no cycles in the graph, I would try something like:

```
function findLongestPath(tree)
begin

   all_paths := {}

   for each neighbour 
      all_paths.append(create_path(this_node, findLongestPath(three - current_node))

   sort_descending(all_paths)
   return  all_paths[0];
end
```

The algorithm can be further optimised to store just the best path instead of a set (removes the need of storing all possible paths and sorting).